# Download file stored on Amazon S3 with php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download

I have the following code which successfully displays a file saved on S3 to the browser, but I would like to be able to download the file to the client's computer.

What do I need to do?

```
$result = S3::getObject($Bucketname,$uri);
header("Content-Type: ".$result->headers['type']);
die($result->body);
```

I've tried the following, but it just downloads an unreadable file...

```
$result = S3::getObject($Bucketname,$uri);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.pdf');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($result->body));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($result->body);
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a download url, using the getObjectUrl method

somthing like:

```
$downloadUrl = $s3->getObjectUrl($bucketname, $file, '+5 minutes', array(
                'ResponseContentDisposition' => 'attachment; filename=$file,'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
        ));
```

and pass that url to the user. that will direct the user to an amzon page which will start the file download (the link will be valid for 5 minutes - but you can change that)

another option, is first saving that file to your server, and then let the user download the file from your server

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to download a pdf as a binary content type data.

Use the response of your getObject request to get the proper mime type:

```
$result = S3::getObject($Bucketname,$uri);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: ' . $result['ContentType']);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.pdf');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($result->body));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($result->body);
exit;
```